# infinite_scroll_pagination change the state of the element on scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state

I am using the AutomaticKeepAliveMixin as well but no luck. below is the complete code.
In the PagedListView, addAutomaticKeepAlive is also set to true but no luck.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:familyapp/models/newsdatemodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:familyapp/theme/texttheme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import '../../appconstants/applocale.dart';
import '../../appconstants/deviceInfo.dart';
import '../loginflow/signin.dart';
import 'newsdatedetail.dart';

class NewsAndDate extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewsAndDate({super.key});
  static String routeName = '/ArticleList';
  static const _pageSize = 10;
  @override
  State<NewsAndDate> createState() => _NewsAndDateState();
}

class _NewsAndDateState extends State<NewsAndDate> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<NewsAndDate> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  final PagingController<int, NewsDateData> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    // print(pageKey);
    String baseUrl =
        '${DeviceInfo.baseUrl}/api/v1/news-date/list?page=$pageKey';
    final uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl);
    try {
      final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'device-id': DeviceInfo.deviceId!,
        'device-type': DeviceInfo.deviceType!,
        'locale': AppLocale.appLanguage.toString(),
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${DeviceInfo.token}',
      });
      final _decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      List<NewsDateData>? newItems;
      // print('hi');
      print(_decodedResponse);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        newItems = NewsAndDateModel.fromJson(_decodedResponse).data!.data;
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        // RenewToken();
      } else if (response.statusCode == 403) {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(SigninScreen.routeName, (route) => false);
      }
      final isLastPage = newItems!.length < NewsAndDate._pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('error is $error');
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }

  List<String> dateList = [];
  Widget containDate() {
    return const SizedBox();
  }

  Widget notContainDate(String date) {
    dateList.add(date);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TextThemeWidget(
                      fontSize: 13,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      text: 'Georgian Year',
                      fontColor: ColorTheme.primaryyColor),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'lib/assets/images/Vector-90.png',
                        color: ColorTheme.primaryyColor,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      TextThemeWidget(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        text: date,
                        fontColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TextThemeWidget(
                      fontSize: 13,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      text: 'Hijri Year',
                      fontColor: ColorTheme.primaryyColor),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'lib/assets/images/Vector-90.png',
                        color: ColorTheme.primaryyColor,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      TextThemeWidget(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        text: date,
                        fontColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Divider(
            color: ColorTheme.primaryyColor,
            thickness: 2,
            height: 2,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextThemeWidget(
          fontSize: 17,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          text: AppLocalizations.of(context).news_and_date,
          fontColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: PagedListView(
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
          pagingController: _pagingController,
          builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<NewsDateData>(
            noItemsFoundIndicatorBuilder: (context) {
              return Center(
                child: TextThemeWidget(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  text: AppLocalizations.of(context).data_not_found,
                  fontColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              );
            },
            firstPageErrorIndicatorBuilder: (context) {
              return Center(
                child: TextThemeWidget(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  text: AppLocalizations.of(context).data_not_found,
                  fontColor: Colors.black,
                ),
              );
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => Column(
              children: [
                dateList.contains(item.publishAt.toString())
                    ? containDate()
                    : notContainDate(item.publishAt!.toString()),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      bool? val = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                          NewsDateDetailNews.routeName,
                          arguments: item) as bool?;
                      if (mounted) {
                        if (val != null) {
                          _pagingController.refresh();
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Html(data: item.description),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want the code to work like this

[image] but when I scroll it changes to

[image]

I want to show the news year wise. I am using column widget for that. If the year is not added in the datelist than I will show the year, but if it is already added than I am showing the empty Sizedbox. But when I scroll the list the state of the elements changes but the condition (year is added in datelist) remains set to true.